# Use a tex file solely for command definitions

Tags: macros

I would like to use a .tex file with all my custom command definitions, but I do not know how I can then use these commands in my `main.tex` file. I know about `\include` and `\input`, but iirc these are used to insert pages into your eventual document, right?

Comment: You want `\input`. Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/82917

Comment: You can use `\input{mycommands}` in the preamble as well only for commands in a `.tex` file, but if you will use a set of commands consistently in several documents, consider make a package (`.sty` extension) or even your own class (`.cls` extension) in order to simplify the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\input` if the file has an extension `.tex` but better give the file the extension `.sty`, say `mycommands.sty` then use `\usepackage{mycommands}` in the preamble.